# While uploading i want to overwrite existing blob using Azure blob Storage method uploadFromFile()

Tags: java, azure, upload, azure-blob-storage, azure-container-service

i wanted to use uploadFromFile(String filePath, boolean overwrite) method of Azure. But it don't have the method. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vvbuu.png)

How can i be able to overwrite the existing blob azure. Answers highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below maven dependency `12.16.0` version for `azure- storage-blob`:

```
<dependency> 
<groupId>com.azure</groupId> 
<artifactId>azure-storage-blob</artifactId>   
<version>12.16.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And we can use the `uploadFromFile` method as suggested in the below code from this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.storage.blob.blobclient.uploadfromfile?view=azure-java-stable#com-azure-storage-blob-blobclient-uploadfromfile%28java-lang-string-boolean%29):

```java
    try {
     boolean overwrite = false; 
     client.uploadFromFile(filePath, overwrite);
     System.out.println("Upload from file succeeded"); 
     } catch (UncheckedIOException ex) { 
     System.err.printf("Failed to upload from file %s%n", ex.getMessage());
      }
```